# Getting ADF from PPSE by android Pay applicatons

Tags: nfc, apdu, emv, contactless-smartcard

I'm trying to read a smartcard information by android pay application. So I send the following SELECT PPSE command:

```
00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
```

I get the following response:
[image: 2PAY.SYS.DDF01]

That is, I need to get an ADF <A0 00 00 06 58 10 10>, but when I try to get it by SELECT:

```
00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 06 58 10 10
```

I get the following response:

```
SW1SW2 = 6A82: File not found.
```

The tag 9F2A in PPSE means that I need to use Kernel specification (Kernel 1 for me).
But the documentation talks about actions from the moment when there is already a PDOL.

How do I get the PDOL if the ADF in which it is located is not found?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application is not enabled, you need to use a set status command to enable the application and please retry